# Understanding how boost::lockfree::queue works

Tags: c++, boost, queue, atomic, lock-free

I want to understand how does boost::lockfree::queue work, it is a multi-writer/multi-reader queue, using atomics to enforce memory ordering and hence thread safety.
I am interested in the details of how the underlying code works, I did read up the code for `boost::lockfree:spsc_queue` and it was graspable, but I cant seem to get my head around this one.

Can anyone help with a big-picture type view keeping the critical steps as well? Any existing resources to this is also appreciated.

Comment: https://youtu.be/c1gO9aB9nbs

Comment: The boost lock-free MPMC queue is an implementation of the queue proposed in [Simple, Fast, and Practical Non-Blocking and Blocking
Concurrent Queue Algorithms](https://www.cs.rochester.edu/~scott/papers/1996_PODC_queues.pdf) by Maged Michael and Michael Scott. The referenced paper should contain all the details you need to understand the queue itself. The boost implementation is a bit more complex since it also uses its own free-list with tagged pointers to solve the memory reclamation problem. I am not sure with which bit you are struggling though - the queue or the free-list stuff.

Comment: `boost::lockfree::queue` may not be the best performer amongst its peers in some [benchmarks](https://max0x7ba.github.io/atomic_queue/html/benchmarks.html).

Comment: this benchmark is very interesting and helped me understand a lot of other things about inter-thread communication by digging into individual projects as well (SPSC cases as of now). Thanks a lot @MaximEgorushkin :D